# Video stream testing

Tags: testing, video, stream

I've got some distance learning software, yesterday I've got near 1000 users watching video simultaneously. My client told me that server was down and memory was exceeded.

It asp.net website and server language is C#. I'm using `Response.TransmitFile(...)` for streaming videos. Is there any way to simulate 1000 simultaneously video stream situation to figure out what's going on, cause when I'm testing the website everything works fine.

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler? http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: I've already moved all my video files to amazon, rather than my webserver. So this problem has been fixed almost 2 years ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not ever use your web server as video streaming server, there is no chance you can succeed.

I personally moved my videos to Amazon Web Services and I'm very satisfied with that.

Comment: Finally after 2 years :)